# How to use cURL to GET api data within PHP

Tags: php

I have an API and documentation states on how to use and it should be like this:

```
curl -X 'GET' \
  'https://example.com/api/v2/{type}/{query}?timeout=60' \
  -H 'accept: application/json' \
  -H 'api-key: 123
```

I found the following code and replaced but didn't work

The api.php code I tried:

```
<?php

if(!isset($_POST["keyword"]))
{
 echo "missing a required data";
 exit;
}
function get_uid($param_val){
    
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Accept: application/json'));

    $param = "email";
    if (!filter_var($param_val, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        $param = "phone";
        $param_val = urlencode($param_val);
    }
    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
      CURLOPT_URL => "https://example.com/api/v2/{type}/{query}?timeout=60/by-token?token=123=".$param_val,
      CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
      CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
      CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
      CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
      CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
      CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
      CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
      CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
        
      ),
    ));

    $response = curl_exec($curl);
    if (curl_errno($curl)) {
        $error_msg = curl_error($curl);
    }
    curl_close($curl);
    
    return $response;   
    
}
```

What modification should I do inside api.php for this:

```
curl -X 'GET' \
  'https://example.com/api/v2/{type}/{query}?timeout=60' \
  -H 'accept: application/json' \
  -H 'api-key: 123
```

To work

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set additional curl option as headers as :

```
$headers = [
    'accept: application/json',
    'api-key: 123'
];

CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $headers
```